# Qtxmath package with MiKTeX

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I was planning to test the qtxmath package with the tgtermes fonts with MiKTeX 2.9:

```
\usepackage{qtxmath,tgtermes}
```

However, I encounter problems compiling the document:

miktex-makemf: The qtmri source file could not be found.
Running hbf2gf.exe...
hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.3)
Couldn't find `qtm.cfg'
miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font qtmri.
! Font \csname\endcsname=qtmri at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fo
und.
 
                   \endgroup \set@typeset@protect 
l.30 \end{document}

?

The problem has been described in the Internet, but I have found no solutions for it. Perhaps I can use some other packages to get the same result?

Many thanks,

Radek

Comment: Typically, it is `psfonts.map` and the like that was not updated. Try running in console : `updmap.exe` both in administrator mode and in user mode.

Comment: Did this, but there is no difference... Is there anything else worth doing after running updmap.exe? I see no result of running this command.

Comment: Maybe refresh the FNDB first. I can't test, as I don't know where `qtxmath.sty` comes from.

Comment: Tried:) But no luck.

Comment: Where does `qtxmath` come from?

Comment: Here is some description: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-2/tb95heff-gyre.pdf

Comment: OK. This package seems to be obsolete. You should load `newtxtext, newtxmath` (in that order) instead. The first will load `tg-termes` and use `URW Nimbus` for maths. Alternatively, you can use `unicode-math` and `fontspec` and set Tex Gyre Termes as text and math fonts, compiling with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.